# What is the JSP EL equivalent for request.getRemoteUser()?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, el

I'm using `<%=request.getRemoteUser()%>` to retrieve the logged on user's ID within Tomcat.  What would be the equivalent using JSP Simple Expression Language?

Answer (score 9):

It's

```
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```

To learn more about implicit EL objects like [`PageContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html), have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij).